# Full page PDF in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I am trying to get a full page PDF using `puppeteer` and my code is like this,
But the resultant is multiple pages with the height equal to that of the page.

How do i resolve this? TIA.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto("http://localhost:3000/longpage", {
        waitUntil: "networkidle2"
    });

    let height = await page.evaluate(
        () => document.documentElement.offsetHeight
    );

    console.log("Height", height);

    await page.pdf({
        path: "hni.pdf",
        printBackground: true,
        margin: "none",
        height: height + "px"
    });

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: does the page have any css tied to it? Are you using any page breaks?

Comment: @karthick Yes, It has CSS both media and print. I deployed the webpage at https://blissful-hopper-cf61f9.netlify.com/. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [page you linked](https://blissful-hopper-cf61f9.netlify.com/) uses Bootstrap, which has the following rule in its set (you can find it [here](https://blissful-hopper-cf61f9.netlify.com/static/css/2.298b87f9.chunk.css)):

```css
@page{size:a3}
```

This will limit the height of the page to the size of `a3`.

You can either remove the rule (or Bootstrap altogether) from the website or add the following code before calling `page.pdf`:

```js
await page.addStyleTag({
    content: '@page { size: auto; }',
})
```

Comment: Hey Thomas, It works, it prints the entire thing in one page but it prints the mobile version instead of `@media print`, If i use `page.emulateMedia("print");` still it's the mobile version But, it's a multiple page PDF with the height of print :/

Comment: Hey,

I managed to get it working using your answer w/ a little tweak. Instead od `auto` i set it like this - `content: @page { size:${width}px ${height}px;}`. I am retrieving `width` and `height` using `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth` respectively.

Comment: @Nithin Nice, feel free to edit the answer if you want to add it to the answer :)

Comment: Yep, Will add it as a comment.

Comment: I am using the same above code. But my page height is 7500px. The content beyond 6000px is not printing in the PDF. Can you help with this @Nithin  and Thomas Dondorf. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also asked it as a seperate question you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63603589/content-is-missing-at-the-end-of-the-pdf-while-generated-through-puppeteer for more details.
Can anyone please help on this.