# Content is missing at the end of the PDF while generated through puppeteer

Tags: pdf, puppeteer, chromium

I am trying to generate the PDF by sending the URL to puppeteer. I gave specific height and width as options to page.pdf method. I am able to get the exact height of the PDF but at the end some content is missing. And it is only happening with more height PDF's.

Below is my code:

```
  let pdf = {};
        const puppeteerArguments = [];
        
        puppeteerArguments.push('--disable-web-security', '--allow-running-insecure-content', '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--no-first-run',
            '--hide-scrollbars',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            '--allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt',
            '--enable-hardware-overlays',
            '--start-fullscreen'
            );


        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, args: puppeteerArguments, sloMo: 0});

        const page = await browser.newPage();

        const {url} = payload;

        await page.setViewport({
            width: 1024,
            height: 7500,
            deviceScaleFactor: 1,
            isMobile: false
        });

        page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
            "cookie": '******',
        });


        await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0}).then(() => {
            console.log('load success');
        });

        await page.emulateMedia('screen');

        await page.addStyleTag({
            content: `
                  html {
                    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
                    -webkit-filter: opacity(1) !important;
               }`
        });

        const selector = '.widgetsRendered'
        await page.waitForFunction(selector => !!document.querySelector(selector), {polling: 600, timeout: 0}, selector);
        
        await page.waitFor(20000);

        const path = `fullPage.pdf`;

        pdf = await page.pdf({
            path,
            width: 1560 + 'px',
            height: 7500 + 'px',
            scale: 1,
            displayHeaderFooter: false,
            margin: 'none',
            printBackground: true,
        });
        return pdf;
```

I am using `"puppeteer": "^2.1.1"`

Below is the image of the issue.

[image]

Can some one please help.

Comment: If you would like to get some answers, you would need to work more on your question. At least consider posting the code which loads the content and converts it to PDF.

Comment: Edited my question with code, TQ for the suggesion @SlavaIvanov

Comment: In `goto` consider using `networkidle0`; `networkidle2` doesn't guarantee the page is loaded completely; The `height` evaluation has some magic number of 200, something weird going on with height, requires debugging; In `pdf` you set path to store the document and in the same time return binary of it, why; You have the range of one page only, but screenshot you posted shows page delimiter, so at least 2 pages, what is it. I don't think somebody provides you with solution, this is something you need to debug.

Comment: I would advise setting browser into the headed mode, comment out PDF conversion part and see how your content is loaded; get the sizes of your containers with dev tools, compared to what you have calculated as your evaluation. Basically debug it properly till the PDF conversion and after review your `pdf` options you are setting. Just put some time debugging your code. Best regards,

Comment: @SlavaIvanov Thanks for the reply
I debugged the code and in the devtools it is giving me the correct height. Ignore height calculation from the above code and returning ```pdf```. I checked the height of the page in my browser and added height manually to the above code in ```pdf options```. By this I  am able to get the given height of the PDF but the content is missing at the end. And the image i posted has widgets the break you see is widget end But not page break.

Comment: Does the page loaded completely, when using headed mode? Did you try to use `networkidle0`? `deviceScaleFactor` set to 4, is this intentional? In `pdf` `fullPage` option doesn't exist, this is from `screenshot`, remove it. Would you try to render PDF without particular height, just everything you have? Anyway, sorry man, this is all about debugging and trying new options, you would need to do this on your own.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov I tried by adding networkidle0 and setting  ```deviceScaleFactor``` to 4 is not intentional. I removed ```fullPage```  option. I am debugging the issue.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov by removing the ```setViewport()``` method and passing ```defaultViewport: null``` in launch method I am able to get the entire page content but now i am facing issues with width unable to get the exact width of content.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `-webkit-filter: opacity(1) !important;` from content of `addStyleTag` method resolved my issue.