# Puppeteer: how to generate PDF that only has one page and the page contains all content of webpage

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, puppeteer

I'm trying to generate  pdf with Puppeteer. What I would like to have is that the generated pdf file should only have one page. And this single page contains all content of the webpage.

Following is my code, which is copied from https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5590#issuecomment-747638812

But it doesn't work as expected.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    defaultViewport: {
      width: 1024,
      height: 800,
    },
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--hide-scrollbars',
      '--start-fullscreen',
    ]
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.w3schools.com/', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
  });
  await page.emulateMediaType('screen');

  const totalPage = await page.$('html');
  const boundingBox = await totalPage.boundingBox();
  console.log(boundingBox);

  await page.pdf({
    path: 'w3schools.pdf', 
    printBackground: true,
    width: '1024px',
    height: `${boundingBox.height + 20}px`,
  });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610614/full-page-pdf-in-puppeteer) this works!

Comment: What if the webpage doesn't fit on a single PDF page?

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, the cleaner way to do that, would be using [`page.eval()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v12.0.1&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to get the document's height and passing it as an option to [`page.pdf()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v12.0.1&show=api-pagepdfoptions)

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const docHeight = () => {
  const body = document.body
  const html = document.documentElement;
  return Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
}

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript");
    const height = await page.evaluate(docHeight);

    await page.pdf({path: `js.pdf`, height: `${height}px`})
    
})();
```

Comment: Improve this idea, const elem = await page.$("html"); const boundingBox = await elem.boundingBox();
 await page.pdf({
      path: "html.pdf",
      printBackground: true,
      height: `${boundingBox.height}px`
    });

Comment: yeah. I al so applied this way.. but problem is its keeps a specific ammount of extra space at the bottom of page.

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/22675563/, `Math.max(body.scrollHeight, html.scrollHeight)` should be enough.